# setting AVAudioFormat to connect function has crash

Tags: crash, avfoundation, swift3, avaudioengine

I have been trying play with AVAudioEngine for singed 16 bit stream data.

But pass to AVAudioFormat connect function always make crash.

codes like below:

```
let AUDIO_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE    = 44100
let AUDIO_OUTPUT_CHANNELS       = 2
let AUDIO_OUTPUT_BITS           = 16
var audioEngine: AVAudioEngine?
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayerNode?

...

    audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayerNode()

    audioEngine?.attach(audioPlayer!)

    let mixer = audioEngine?.mainMixerNode
    mixer!.outputVolume = 1.0
    let stereoFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt16, sampleRate: Double(AUDIO_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE), channels: 2, interleaved: false)
    audioEngine!.connect(audioPlayer!, to: mixer!, format: stereoFormat)

...
```

audioEngine!.connect(...) is crashing line

I'm using Xcode 8 beta 6, OS X El Capitan, And, this happening arise from both of simulator and devices.

This is part of crash message:

```
ERROR:    >avae> AVAudioNode.mm:751: AUSetFormat: error -10868
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'error -10868'

...
3   AVFAudio  0x000000011e0a5630 _Z19AVAE_RaiseExceptionP8NSStringz + 176
4   AVFAudio  0x000000011e0f270d _ZN19AVAudioNodeImplBase11AUSetFormatEP28OpaqueAudioComponentInstancejjP13AVAudioFormat + 213
5   AVFAudio  0x000000011e0f2630 _ZN19AVAudioNodeImplBase15SetOutputFormatEmP13AVAudioFormat + 46
6   AVFAudio  0x000000011e0f9663 _ZN21AVAudioPlayerNodeImpl15SetOutputFormatEmP13AVAudioFormat + 25
7   AVFAudio  0x000000011e099cfd _ZN18AVAudioEngineGraph8_ConnectEP19AVAudioNodeImplBaseS1_jjP13AVAudioFormat + 2377
8   AVFAudio  0x000000011e09d15f _ZN18AVAudioEngineGraph7ConnectEP11AVAudioNodeS1_mmP13AVAudioFormat + 355
9   AVFAudio  0x000000011e0fc80e _ZN17AVAudioEngineImpl7ConnectEP11AVAudioNodeS1_mmP13AVAudioFormat + 348
```

It's no problem playing with buffer and format from audio file.

What is mistake(s) I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-10868, a.k.a. `kAudioUnitErr_FormatNotSupported`, so it looks like your `PCMFormatInt16` isn't appreciated. Changing it to `.PCMFormatFloat32` does work.

Comment: I met the same situation and used Float32 to fix it. I noticed that the default AudioFormat in outputNode is also Float32 on 3 different iOD devices. Does that mean iOS device only support playback in Float32?

Answer (score 2):

From Apple, [AVAudioPlayerNode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayernode)

> When playing buffers, there's an implicit assumption that the buffers are at the same sample rate as the node’s output format.

and then print `AVAudioPlayerNode`'s output format, which is `engine.mainMixerNode.inputFormat`

```
    open func connectNodes() {
        print(engine.mainMixerNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0))
        engine.connect(playerNode, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: readFormat)
    }
```

The result is

> <AVAudioFormat 0x6000024c18b0:  2 ch,  44100 Hz, Float32, non-inter>

so choose `.pcmFormatFloat32`, instead of `.pcmFormatInt16`

---

[OSStatus master website](https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-10868)

Answer (score 2):

You need not to create the audio format yourself,

Get the audio format from the actual audio data ( pcm buffer or audio file )

> the audio format thing from WWDC 2016 , Delivering an Exceptional Audio Experience

[image: 0]

---

> The actual audio format theory from WWDC 2015, What's New in Core Audio

- the actual audio format from output

[image: 44]

- the actual audio format from input

[image: 44]

- do audio channel mapping, and audio bit depth keeps the same

[image: 222]

Answer (score 0):

You can use singed 16 bit audio format, but you should convert it at first.

```swift
// Setup your own format
let inputFormat = AVAudioFormat(
    commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt16,
    sampleRate: 44100,
    channels: AVAudioChannelCount(2),
    interleaved: true
)!

let engine = AVAudioEngine()
// Use system format as output format
let outputFormat = engine.mainMixerNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
self.converter = AVAudioConverter(from: inputFormat, to: outputFormat)!

self.playerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
engine.attach(playerNode)
engine.connect(playerNode, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: nil)

...

// Prepare input and output buffer
let inputBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: inputFormat, frameCapacity: maxSamplesPerBuffer)!
let outputBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: outputFormat, frameCapacity: maxSamplesPerBuffer)!

// When you fill your Int16 buffer with data, send it to converter
self.converter.convert(to: outputBuffer, error: nil) { inNumPackets, outStatus in
    outStatus.pointee = .haveData
    return inputBuffer
}

// Now in outputBuffer sound in system format and we can play it
self.playerNode.scheduleBuffer(outputBuffer)
```